# hiding/showing navigation in a angularjs page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a navigation in my main page which is only necessary for logged in users.Now i want to hide the navigation from the login page.So initially i am using an undefined flag variable to hide the navigation in the login page.Then after user login i am setting the flag value as 1 and redirecting to dashboard page so that for the dashboard page the navigation appear.But the problem is though i am successfully setting the flag value the navigation menu is no more appearing.It seems the flag value is making no effect.

In a nutshell my goal is to hide navigation menu from login page but show  this to all other page.So how to solve the issue ? am i moving to the right direction or there are better ways to achieve this ?

Index.htm

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="logCtrl">
    <div ng-if="flag==1"> 
      <p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>
      <a href="#login">Login</a>
      <a href="#dashboard">dashborad</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-view></div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
          templateUrl : "login.htm"
        })
        .when("/login", {
          templateUrl : "login.htm",
          controller : "logCtrl"
        })
        .when("/dashborad", {
          templateUrl : "dashborad.htm",
          controller : "dashboradCtrl"
        });
    });


    app.controller('logCtrl', function ($scope,$location,$http) {
      $scope.login = function () {
        var request = $http({
          method: "post",
          url: "ajax/login.php",
          data: {
            username: $scope.username,
            password: $scope.password
          },
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });

        request.success(function (data) {
          if(data == "1") {
            $scope.flag=1;
            $location.path('/dashboard');
          } else {
            $scope.flag=0;
          }
        });
      }
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

login.htm

```
<div class="panel panel-body login-form">                           
  <div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">
  </div>  
  <div class="form-control-feedback">
      <i class="icon-user text-muted"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
  <div class="form-control-feedback">
    <i class="icon-lock2 text-muted"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<span>{{responseMessage }}{{flag}}</span>                               
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="login()">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `$scope.flag = 1;` executed? Add `{{ flag }}` into your view and check if value `1` was set correctly. Where do you call `$scope.login()`?

Comment: Use data === "1" in order to make sure that you are really receiving string , but not the number or object.

Comment: @andrey.shedko this is simply wrong. No need for a explicit type compare here. He is also not setting a string value, he sets a number.

Comment: @lin, may you guarantee that it always string?

Comment: @andrey.shedko take a look at the scope. He binds a number, its never ever an string.

Comment: Query, please answer my questions.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to use `ng-if` together with `ng-controller` on the same element, when the expression relates to the data that is set in the controller used with `ng-controller`. Also `ng-if` creates a new child scope, so we need to use a so-called dot-rule: "there should always be a dot in your model".

Comment: @lin $scope.flag = 1; is executed and i am successfully receiving the value in view and  i am  calling $scope.login() from my login page

Comment: @StanislavKvitash what do you mean by dot rule ? does it mean to access data i always need to use dot ?

Comment: @query Yes, that's recommended when dealing with the complexities of scope inheritance. You can also use [`controller as` syntax](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) and it will force you to write the dots in your views :)

Answer (score 0):

**Just an advice:**
You better use the usual boolean value for that like `$scope.flag = true` or `$scope.flag = false`. And in you `ng-if`:

```
<div ng-controller="logCtrl" ng-if="flag">
```

**In your controller:**

```
app.controller('logCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
        $scope.login = function () {
                var request = $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "ajax/login.php",
                    data: {
                        username: $scope.username,
                        password: $scope.password
                    },
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
                });

                request.success(function (data) {
                    if(data == "1"){
                       $scope.flag = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.flag = false;
                    }
                });
        }
});
```

And I agree with @StanislavKvitash, it's not a good idea to use `ng-if` and `ng-controller` on the same tag. Better add another one inner `div` and set `ng-if` to it. So try to use this HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="logCtrl">
        <div ng-if="flag">
            <p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

            <a href="#login">Red</a>
            <a href="#dashboard">Green</a>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div ng-view></div>
   ...
</body>
```

**"My goal is to hide navigation menu from login page but show this to all other page"**

If you want to hide navigation only for `/login`, you can simply hardcode flag value at the beginning of your `logCtrl` like this: `$scope.flag = 0` and the navigation will be hidden when `/login` (and you doesn't need `if/else` statement, just hardcode the flag value).

Comment: How does this solve the users question? It doesnt matter if he compares a `string`, `number`, `object`, `array` or a `boolean` at all.

Comment: About boolean usage - it's just an advice. As @StanislavKvitash mentioned, the problem should be in `ng-controller="logCtrl"` and `ng-if="flag"` in the same tag, I'm working to make the answer better and more usefull.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide i have updated my question kindly check!

Comment: @query, I have updated the answer, check this out (at the bottom)

Comment: @CommercialSuicide if i use $scope.flag = 0 then navigation not only hide  for login page but also for all the page because the  navigation is under logCtrl controller so the value of flag remain always false! I even tried setting the   $scope.flag = 1 after login but no effect!

Comment: @query, Try to delete `ng-controller="logCtrl"` attribute from HTML, it should be automatically added (it's written in your route config: `.when("/login", {
                templateUrl : "login.htm",
                controller : "logCtrl"
            })`). And it applies *login.htm*, if I understand correctly, you need to change only *login.htm* (if navigation is in it. So you can just remove navigation from here and may be you don't really need any flags).

Comment: @CommercialSuicide i have no navigation in login.htm the navigation is actually in the main.htm which contain a navigation and it has no controller but it contains all the routing info and other controllers.As the ng-view is defined in the main page  that's why the navigation is shown all the pages but i want to avoid this common navigation in login page!For your convenience i have updated my question by including my login page.

Comment: @query, "the navigation is actually in the main.htm which contain a navigation and it has no controller". Here is the problem: you don't have a controller for you *main.html*. You need to have this controller if you want to control anything in *main.html*. Try to create the controller for it and replace the existing logic with flags to the controller of *main.html*. I almost sure that it should solve the problem.

Comment: totally getting puzzled no solution is working!can you share how you deal such situation i mean when every page like signup sign in and account pages are defined in same page ? do you use navigation for every page instead of using a common layout ?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide My main.htm page is just like an index page and i do not need to route to index page in any situation .when a user visit the site he will automatically access the index page and this page will route the user according to rule  as it is just used to define route  for other so how can i use a controller for it as I will never  route to this page ?

Comment: In your case I advice to create the layout (including navigation, lets call it **layout**) and necessarily create a controller for this layout (lets call it **LayoutCtrl**). Then you can use `view` to dynamically display different pages, and you can show/hide the navigation from **layout**, but the logic for it (your flags) should be in the **LayoutCtrl**, not in **LoginCtrl** or other one. May be it's not very good explanation, but I hope you will catch the main thought.